# Extract common values pairs for multiple dataframes to create a new binary dataframe based on them

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes

```
Drug<-c("ab","bc","cd","ef","gh")
Target<-c("qwewr","saff","cxzcc","sadda","sadd")
fileA<-data.frame(Drug,Target)


Drug<-c("ab","bc","cdD","efc","ghg","hj")
Target<-c("qwewr","saff","cxzccf","saddav","sadd","bn")
fileB<-data.frame(Drug,Target)


Drug<-c("abB","bcv","cdD","efc")
Target<-c("qwewrm","saff","cxzccfh","saddav")
fileC<-data.frame(Drug,Target)
```

As you can see each one contains a pair "Drug"-"Target". Every dataframe contains only unique pairs. But you can find exactly the same pair in the other dataframes. What I want to achieve is to create a new dataframe which will extract all the unique pairs in the first column and then in the other 3 columns will have the `fileA, fileB` and `fileC` which will be filled with `1` if the pair exists and `0` if the pair does not exist. Something like:

```
Pairs fileA fileB fileC
 1:    abqwewr     1     1     1
 2:     bcsaff     1     1     1
 3:    cdcxzcc     1     1     1
 4:    efsadda     1     1     1
 5:     ghsadd     1     1     0
 6:  cdDcxzccf     0     0     0
 7:  efcsaddav     0     0     0
 8:    ghgsadd     0     0     0
 9:       hjbn     0     0     0
10:  abBqwewrm     0     0     0
11:    bcvsaff     0     0     0
12: cdDcxzccfh     0     0     0
```

But here the dataframe is not correct since in the first column there is only the drug name and also each row should have had at least one `1`.

My method:

```
# Create composite dataset by combining all files
compositeDataD <- rbind(fileA,fileB,fileC)


# Get unique (drug, target) pairs
# Connect Drug Names and Target Gene Symbols into one vector of pairs
compositeDataD <- na.omit(compositeDataD)
DrugTargetPairsD <- paste(compositeDataD$Drug,compositeDataD$Target,sep="")
uniquePairsD<-unique(DrugTargetPairsD)

PairsA <- DrugTargetPairsD[1:nrow(na.omit(fileA))]
PairsB <- DrugTargetPairsD[1:nrow(na.omit(fileB))]
PairsC <- DrugTargetPairsD[1:nrow(na.omit(fileC))]

# Create binary matrix for unique (drug, target) pairs 


binaryA <- as.numeric(uniquePairsD %in% PairsA) # This function returns a binary value for each unique (Drug, Target) Pair compared with the content of file1
binaryB <- as.numeric(uniquePairsD %in% PairsB)
binaryC <- as.numeric(uniquePairsD %in% PairsC)


table33 <- data.table(Pairs=uniquePairsD,
                     fileA=binaryA,fileB=binaryB,
                     fileC=binaryC)
```

Comment: `fileC: "abB","bcv" -> "ab","bc"` . Double error from you???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create the Pairs and then merge on them, while carrying a column where the data came from:

Create the indicator column in each file:

```
fileA$fileA <- 1
fileB$fileB <- 1
fileC$fileC <- 1
```

Create the pairs in each file:

```
fileA$DrugTargetPair <- paste0(fileA$Drug, fileA$Target)
fileB$DrugTargetPair <- paste0(fileB$Drug, fileB$Target)
fileC$DrugTargetPair <- paste0(fileC$Drug, fileC$Target)
```

Select only the indicator column and the Pairs colum :

```
fileA <- fileA[, c("DrugTargetPair", "fileA")]
fileB <- fileB[, c("DrugTargetPair", "fileB")]
fileC <- fileC[, c("DrugTargetPair", "fileC")]
```

Merge on the Pairs column, kepp all Pairs with `all = T`:

```
file_new <- merge(fileA, fileB, by = "DrugTargetPair", all = T)
file_new <- merge(file_new, fileC, by = "DrugTargetPair", all = T)
file_new[is.na(file_new)] <- 0

file_new
   DrugTargetPair fileA fileB fileC
1       abBqwewrm     0     0     1
2         abqwewr     1     1     0
3          bcsaff     1     1     0
4         bcvsaff     0     0     1
5         cdcxzcc     1     0     0
6       cdDcxzccf     0     1     0
7      cdDcxzccfh     0     0     1
8       efcsaddav     0     1     1
9         efsadda     1     0     0
10        ghgsadd     0     1     0
11         ghsadd     1     0     0
12           hjbn     0     1     0
```

Comment: I ll take that as fits better my original case.tnx

Answer (score 5):

Form list `L` from the three objects and use `lapply` to paste their columns together and then `stack` to create a 2 column data frame with the pasted values and an indicator of which object it came from.  Finally use `table` to provide the counts.

```
L <- mget(ls(pattern = "file"))
s <- stack(lapply(L, function(x) paste0(x[[1]], x[[2]])))
table(s)
```

giving:

```
            ind
values       fileA fileB fileC
  abBqwewrm      0     0     1
  abqwewr        1     1     0
  bcsaff         1     1     0
  bcvsaff        0     0     1
  cdcxzcc        1     0     0
  cdDcxzccf      0     1     0
  cdDcxzccfh     0     0     1
  efcsaddav      0     1     1
  efsadda        1     0     0
  ghgsadd        0     1     0
  ghsadd         1     0     0
  hjbn           0     1     0
```

A variation of this is to express it as this pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
mget(ls(pattern = "file")) %>%
  lapply(function(x) paste0(x[[1]], x[[2]])) %>%
  stack %>%
  table
```

Comment: holy cow ! Thats neat.

Answer (score 1):

data:

```
Drug<-c("ab","bc","cd","ef","gh")
Target<-c("qwewr","saff","cxzcc","sadda","sadd")
fileA<-data.frame(I(Drug),I(Target))


Drug<-c("ab","bc","cdD","efc","ghg","hj")
Target<-c("qwewr","saff","cxzccf","saddav","sadd","bn")
fileB<-data.frame(I(Drug),I(Target))


Drug<-c("abB","bcv","cdD","efc")
Target<-c("qwewrm","saff","cxzccfh","saddav")
fileC<-data.frame(I(Drug),I(Target))
```

code:

```
all_list <- list(fileA, fileB, fileC)

all1 <- rbind(fileA,fileB,fileC)
all1 <- as.data.frame(unique(all1))

ans <- t(apply(all1, 1, function(drgT){ sapply(all_list, function(x) {(list(drgT) %in% unlist(apply(x,1,list), recursive = F))*1} ) }))
ans[rowSums(ans) == 1,] <- 0

cbind(all1, ans)
```

result:

```
#   Drug  Target 1 2 3
#1    ab   qwewr 1 1 0
#2    bc    saff 1 1 0
#3    cd   cxzcc 0 0 0
#4    ef   sadda 0 0 0
#5    gh    sadd 0 0 0
#8   cdD  cxzccf 0 0 0
#9   efc  saddav 0 1 1
#10  ghg    sadd 0 0 0
#11   hj      bn 0 0 0
#12  abB  qwewrm 0 0 0
#13  bcv    saff 0 0 0
#14  cdD cxzccfh 0 0 0
```

---

please note:

- please revise your example data/ desired outcome.
- please [E D U C A T E](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/) yourself on stringsAsFactors.